# MVC5 EF BaseController Execute code only for a controller and a specified action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to run some code only if a particular controller and action is requested.
I tried the below code but - it gives error(`$exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}`
) when other parts of the website is visited.  What  should be the best way to do this.  This is impacting on the page load.

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "Page" && requestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Details")

........
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an action filter that inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute` and add the code you need in the `OnActionExecuting` or `OnActionExecuted`, then annotate the controller or action you want with this attribute

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters